# Hybrid App to count files under local directory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building a hybrid app using Ionic. I have an image that cycles as time goes by. I would like to include all possible images under a specific directory belonging to the app and let the app decide which to show at each time randomly. The other option is just to keep an array with all filenames, but this is prone to errors.

The question is. Despite JavaScript security limitations, can this be done, somehow, using JavaScript under Ionic or angularJS?.

Thanks in advance,

Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hybrid mobile apps can access the file system by using the File plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file). You can then do full CRUD (ie, create/read/update/delete) for both directories and files. Obviously your app can't delete the OS and stuff like that, but in general, you can use the file system to do what you want. This article (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) has some good examples of reading directories.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!. This is what I was looking for.